# Getting Docker CLI automatically installed on server 2016/2019

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, windows-container

Does anyone know how to install docker including docker CLI in an automated way on windows servers??
I have found the following code to enable containerization and install docker engine.

```bsh
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Containers -All
```

reboot here

```bsh
Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Force
Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
```

I try to find docker cli under C:\Program files\Docker\Docker
Everything else is there, CLI plugins, docker.exe, etc.. the packages are also installed successfully on ver 19

I need the docker CLI as I want to automatically move to "windows containers" after the installation

Comment: I'm not a windows server sysadmin but it looks like the only problem you have is that the docker.exe (cli tool) is not in the PATH environment variable

Comment: No, that's not it, docker cli is a different executable in a different path, for example with the dockercli.exe i can run "-SwitchDaemon", a parameter that docker.exe doesn't have

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? have you been able to get docker cli on WS2016?

Comment: @Dabbas nah.. tried to work it, but left it shortly after, containers nor dockers are just not meant for windows ^_^